# Best way to differentiate between class types for different handling

Tags: java, types, enums, overloading, instanceof

I wanted to know what are the advantages / disadvantages of using each of the following ways to differentiate between sub-classes of the main parent class and handle them differently. I know this is pretty basic, but i couldnt find a full comparison between these ways anywhere.

For example: 
- I have a **Payment** super abstract class and two extending classes **OneTimePayment** and **Subscription**
- I have a method **switchPaymentState** that should handle each one of these types differently

- Option 1: Using instanceof

  ```
  public void switchPaymentState(Payment payment) {
    if(payment instanceof OneTimePayment) {
      //do something
    } else if(payment instanceof Subscription) {
      //do something else
    }
  }
  ```
- Option 2: Using enum type argument (or other...)

  ```
  public enum PaymentType {
    ONE_TIME_PAYMENT,
    SUBSCRIPTION;
  }    
  public abstract Payment(PaymentType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  public OneTimePayment() {
     super(ONE_TIME_PAYMENT);
  }
  public Subscription() {
     super(SUBSCRIPTION);
  }
  ```

  and then:

  ```
  public void switchPaymentState(Payment payment) {
    switch(payment.type) {
      case ONE_TIME_PAYMENT:
        //do something
        break;
      case SUBSCRIPTION:
        //do something
        break;
    }
  }
  ```
- Option 3: Using overload methods

  ```
  public void switchPaymentState(OneTimePayment payment){
      //do something
  }
  public void switchPaymentState(Subscription payment){
     //do something
  }
  ```

So, which is the best way to go (or a complete other way?) and why?

**EDIT:**
The operations i need to do based on the class type are NOT operations on the class itself, i need to take some data form the payment and send it via other services, so solutions like implementing this functionality inside the classes and calling it regardless of the type, will unfortunately not help in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I think the 3rd option is the best. If you use the first way, the method will be too long. Method should be short enough. And It has to be not too complex. Each method should perform only one behavior. If you solve the problem in the first way, the complexity of your method will increase. And the second way is not easy to understand in a short time I think.

Comment: I guess switchPaymentState method will behave differently according to the instance type, but the results will be almost same. In this case, overloading is a good option I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 3 will in many cases not work, because overloading is resolved atcompile-time rather than at run-time. If the type of your references is `Payment`, it is not possible to use overloading.

In terms of object-oriented design, using overridden methods is the "cleanest" method. However, it has the disadvantage that similar functionality is spead over multiple classes, whereas in the switch and instanceof solutions everything is together.

An alternative that offers the best of both worlds is the so-called Visitor Pattern. You create an interface `PaymentVisitor` with for each class you want a handle a method, as follows:

```
interface PaymentVisitor {
    void visitOneTimePayment(OneTimePayment payment);
    void visitSubscription(Subscription payment);
}
```

Then in you abstract superclass you add a method visit:

```
abstract class Payment {
    ...
    abstract void callVisitor(PaymentVisitor visitor);
}
```

Which you implement in all you subclasses as follows:

```
class OneTimePayment {
    ...
    @Override void callVisitor(PaymentVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.handleOneTimePayment(this);
    }
}

class Subscription {
    ...
    @Override void callVisitor(PaymentVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.handleSubscription(this);
    }
}
```

Now, in all cases where you would otherwise write something like (in pseudo-Java):

```
switch (type of x) {
    case OneTimePayment:
         // Code
         break;
     case Subscription:
         // Code
         break;
}
```

You can now write, cleanly and type-safe:

```
x.callVisitor(new PaymentVisitor() {
    @Override void handleOneTimePayment(OneTimePayment payment) {
        // Code
    }
    @Override void handleSubscription(Subscription payment) {
        // Code
    }
});
```

Note also that the visitor is implemented in an inner class, so you still have access to all (effectively) final variables defined in the method body.

Comment: Hey, this is also a very good idea, thank you, but unfortunately does not fit my requirements since i cannot really change the implementation of OneTimePayment and Subscription.. but i will for sure think of this pattern in the future

Answer (score 3):

The most modular way would be to use overriding.

You'll have a single `switchPaymentState` method which accepts the base type - Payment - and calls a method in the Payment class to do the handling. That method can be overridden in each sub-class of Payment.

```
public void switchPaymentState(Payment payment)
{
    payment.handlePayment();
}
```

Your `switchPaymentState` method doesn't have to know which sub-classes of Payment exist, and it doesn't have to change if you add new sub-classes tomorrow.

Comment: mmm yeah that would be great but i need to do things outside the class, like sending different HTTP requests for each type and updating different DB tables, to which i do not have access from these classes... but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the switch is a bit of an anti-pattern regardless of how you do it. The more standard OO way would be to implement the same method or methods in both of the subclasses, and let each class manage things as appropriate. In other words

```
abstract class Payment {
    abstract void processPayment(BigDecimal amount);
    abstract void processRefund...
} 

class OneTimePayment extends Payment {
    void processPayment(BigDecimal amount){... }

    void processRefund...
}
```

etc.

Also, unless you're reusing a considerable amount of code in the super class, consider an interface-based implementation instead of subclassing.